# The await operator is not waiting like I expected

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I am working on a class `DelayedExecutor` that will delay the execution of an `Action` passed to its `DelayExecute` method by a certain time `timeout` (see code below) using the async and await statements. I also want to be able to abort the execution within the `timeout` interval if needed. I have written a small test to test its behavior like this:

Code for **Test method**:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public async Task DelayExecuteTest()
    {
        int timeout = 1000;
        var delayExecutor = new DelayedExecutor(timeout);
        Action func = new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Ran function!"));
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds 1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Task delayTask = delayExecutor.DelayExecute(func);
        await delayTask;
        Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds 2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

The output I expected from this test was that it would show me:

> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: ...
>
> Ran Action!"
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: ...
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2:

However I get this and do not understand why:

> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: 0
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: 30
>
> Ran Action!
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: 1015

On this [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) I read:

> I like to think of “await” as an “asynchronous wait”. That is to say, the async method pauses until the awaitable is complete (so it waits), but the actual thread is not blocked (so it’s asynchronous).

This seems to be inline with my expectation, so what is going on here and where is my error?

Code for **DelayedExecutor**:

```
public class DelayedExecutor
{
    private int timeout;

    private Task currentTask;
    private CancellationToken cancellationToken;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

    public DelayedExecutor(int timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void AbortCurrentTask()
    {
        if (currentTask != null)
        {
            if (!currentTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public Task DelayExecute(Action func)
    {
        AbortCurrentTask();

        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

        return currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                await Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);
                func();
                Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            });
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As suggested I modified this line inside my `DelayExecute`

```
return currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

into

```
return currentTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

For this to work I needed to change the signature into this

```
public async Task<Task> DelayExecute(Action func)
```

so that my new definition is this:

```
public async Task<Task> DelayExecute(Action func)
{
    AbortCurrentTask();

    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

    return currentTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);
            func();
            Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        });
}
```

However now I have the same behavior as before. Is there some way achieve what I am trying to do using my design. Or is it fundamentally flawed?

By the way, I also tried putting `await await delayTask;` inside my test `DelayExecuteTest`, but this gives me the error

> Cannot await 'void'

This is the updated test-method `DelayExecuteTest`, which *does not* compile:

```
public async Task DelayExecuteTest()
{
    int timeout = 1000;
    var delayExecutor = new DelayedExecutor(timeout);
    Action func = new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Ran Action!"));
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Task delayTask = delayExecutor.DelayExecute(func);
    await await delayTask;
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Look at the blog [StartNew is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Comment: you need to await twice. `await await delayTask`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bit going on here so I'm going to post a simple answer to begin with, let's see if it suffices.

You'we wrapped a task inside a task, this needs a double await. Otherwise you're only waiting for the inner task to reach its first return point, which will (can) be at the first `await`.

Let's look at your `DelayExecute` method in more detail. Let me begin with changing the return type of the method and we'll see how this changes our perspective. The change of return type is just a clarification. You're returning a `Task` that is nongeneric right now, in reality you're returning a `Task<Task>`.

```
public Task<Task> DelayExecute(Action func)
{
    AbortCurrentTask();

    tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

    return currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            await Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken);
            func();
            Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        });
}
```

*(note that this will not compile since `currentTask` is also of type `Task`, but this is largely irrelevant if you read the rest of the question)*

OK, so what happens here?

Let's explain a simpler example first, I tested this in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

```
async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before await startnew");
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before await delay");
        await Task.Delay(500);
        Console.WriteLine("after await delay");
    });
    Console.WriteLine("after await startnew");
}
```

When executing this I get this output:

```
before await startnew
before await delay
after await startnew
after await delay              -- this comes roughly half a second after previous line
```

So why this?

Well, your `StartNew` returns a `Task<Task>`. This is not a task that now will wait for the inner task to complete, it waits for the inner task to *return*, which it will (can) do at its first `await`.

So let's see the full execution path of this by numbering the interesting lines and then explaining the order in which things happen:

```
async Task Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("before await startnew");           1
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>               2
    {
        Console.WriteLine("before await delay");          3
        await Task.Delay(500);                            4
        Console.WriteLine("after await delay");           5
    });
    Console.WriteLine("after await startnew");            6
}
```

#### 1. The first `Console.WriteLine` executes

nothing magical here

#### 2. We spin up a new task with `Task.Factory.StartNew` and await it.

Here our *main* method can now return, it will return a task that will continue once the inner task has completed.

The job of the inner task is **not** to execute *all* the code in that delegate. The job of the inner task is **to produce yet another task**.

**This is important!**

#### 3. The inner task now starts executing

It will essentially execute all the code in the delegate up to and including the call to `Task.Delay`, which returns a `Task`.

#### 4. The inner task arrives at its first `await`

Since this will not already have completed (it will only complete roughly 500ms later), this delegate **now returns**.

Basically, the `await <this task we got from Task.Delay>` statement will create a continuation and then return.

**This is important!**

#### 6. Our outer task now continues

Since the inner task returned, the outer task can now continue. The result of calling `await Task.Factory.StartNew` is yet another task but **this task is just left to fend for itself**.

#### 5. The inner task, continues roughly 500ms later

This is now after the outer task has already continued, potentially finished executing.

---

So in conclusion your code executes "as expected", just not the way *you* expected.

There are several ways to fix this code, I'm simply going to rewrite your `DelayExecute` method to the simplest way to do what you want to do:

Change this line:

```
    return currentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

Into this:

```
    return currentTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

This will let the inner task start your stopwatch and reach the first await before returning all the way out of `DelayExecute`.

The similar fix to my **LINQPad** example above would be to simply change this line:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

To this:

```
await await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive explanation! I tried your suggestion of changing to the line `return currentTask = await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>`. However then I need to modify the method declaration into an `async`-method with return type `Task<Task> ` like this `public async Task<Task> DelayExecute(Action func)` so that it compiles. So that I seem to be back at the same problem. I also tried adding `await await delayTask;` in the test, which gives me the compile error `cannot await 'void'`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Not without seeing all the code you ended up with, sorry.

Comment: I have a meeting coming up, I will look at your updated code afterwards and test it to see if I can spot the error (either in your code or my answer).

Comment: I figured out how to achieve what I was aiming for and posted that in a second answer. I accepted your answer, since it was the actual issue with my initial code and the answer to my question. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you find an issue with my new version, I would appreciate your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some more thought I figured out, how to achieve what I was aiming for, which is to delay the start of an action and be able to abort it in case I need to. Credit goes to Lasse V. Karlsen for helping me understand the issue.

The answer by Lasse is correct for my original problem, which is why I accepted it. But in case somebody needs to achieve something similar to what I needed, here is how I solved it. I had to use a continuation task after the task started with `StartNew`. I also renamed the method `AbortCurrentTask` into `AbortExecution()`. The new version of my `DelayedExecutor` class is this:

```
public class DelayedExecutor
{
    private int timeout;

    private Task currentTask;
    private CancellationToken cancellationToken;
    private CancellationTokenSource tokenSource;

    public DelayedExecutor(int timeout)
    {
        this.timeout = timeout;
        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public void AbortExecution()
    {
        if (currentTask != null)
        {
            if (!currentTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
            }
        }
    }

    public Task DelayExecute(Action func)
    {
        AbortExecution();

        tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cancellationToken = tokenSource.Token;

        return currentTask =
            Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                if(!t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    func();
                    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

This class now does what I expected from it. These two tests I now give the expected output:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task DelayExecuteTest()
{
    int timeout = 1000;
    var delayExecutor = new DelayedExecutor(timeout);
    Action func = new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Ran Action!"));
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Task delayTask = delayExecutor.DelayExecute(func);
    await delayTask;
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Output:

> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: 0
>
> Ran Action!
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds inside DelayExecute: 3
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: 1020

and

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task AbortDelayedExecutionTest()
{
    int timeout = 1000;
    var delayExecutor = new DelayedExecutor(timeout);
    Action func = new Action(() => Debug.WriteLine("Ran Action!"));
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    Task delayTask = delayExecutor.DelayExecute(func);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    delayExecutor.AbortExecution();
    await delayTask;
    Debug.WriteLine("sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Output:

> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 1: 0
>
> sw.ElapsedMilliseconds outside DelayExecute 2: 122